# Failed to compile error during creating PWA with next.js

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps

I run the command : npm run build

Error :
info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.

Please check your GenerateSW plugin configuration:
[WebpackGenerateSW] 'reactStrictMode' property is not expected to be here. Did you mean property 'exclude'?

> Build failed because of webpack errors

Answer (score 24):

If your version of `next-pwa` is `5.6` and your `next.config.js` is like this:

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')
const runtimeCaching = require('next-pwa/cache')  

module.exports = withPWA({
  pwa: {
    dest: 'public',
    runtimeCaching,
  },
})
```

Then you should consider changing it [as written in the README.md file](https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa#step-1-withpwa):

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')({
  dest: 'public'
})

module.exports = withPWA({
  // next.js config
})
```

I encountered this issue when I followed [the pwa example of nextjs](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/progressive-web-app). My `next-pwa` version is `5.6` and the example's version is `5.5.4`, so it dosen't work.

Comment: Thanks @TechWisdom for correcting my grammar mistakes!

Comment: You welcome @xjw_2000. Thank you for your great answer which helped me a lot! It solved my problem. Keep it up and I wish you enjoy your stay on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: What should be done If i am using next.config.mjs  I mean module instead of cjs

Answer (score 6):

this worked for me

```js
const runtimeCaching = require("next-pwa/cache");
const withPWA = require("next-pwa")({
    dest: "public",
    register: true,
    skipWaiting: true,
    runtimeCaching,
    buildExcludes: [/middleware-manifest.json$/],
});

const nextConfig = withPWA({
    // next config
});
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')({
dest:"public",
register:true,
skipWaiting:true,
disable:process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  })

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
reactStrictMode: true,
 }

module.exports = withPWA(nextConfig);
```